# Is this an adequate proof that T: P --> R, p|-->p(0) is a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, solution-verification

I'm trying to show that the map that sends each polynomial to its value at 0 is a linear transformation.

I am told that T: P --> R (where P is the vector space of polynomials)

and *p*|-->*p*(0)

Here's the proof I came up with:

let p and q be polynomials in P

since T(*p*(x) + *q*(y)) = *p*(0) + *q*(0)

and T(*p*(x)) + T(*q*(y)) = *p*(0) + *q*(0)

T(*p*(x) + *q*(y)) = T(*p*(x)) + T(*q*(y))

let c be any scalar in R

since T(c*p*(x)) = c*p*(0)

and cT(*p*(x)) = c*p*(0)

T(c*p*(x)) = cT(*p*(x))

So T is linear.

Is this the proper way to prove *p*|-->*p*(0)?

Also, I'm not sure if I even need to have the (x) and (y) behind *p* and *q*, or if I should just write it without them (ie. T(*p* + *q*) = *p*(0) + *q*(0) )

Comment: Yes. Looks good.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thank you @copper.hat for verifying!

Comment: oop! Thank you for the tutorial @Shaun! I spent a good 3 minutes looking for a function table to use :)))!